# Geometrical derivation of $\tan(A+B)$

Tags: trigonometry

I wanted to know how to derive $\tan(A+B)=\dfrac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}$ geometrically?

Comment: I assume you have seen the proofs of $\sin(A+B)$ and $\cos(A+B)$ based on a construction with triangles in the trigonometric circle (http://www.clowder.net/hop/cos(a+b).html). Just take the ratio.

Comment: In particular, look at the [diagram for sin/cos addition formula](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/SinCosFormula.shtml) at Cut the Knot.

Comment: Maybe there is a geometric proof without having to resort to those proofs.